# ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic3, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I am getting this warn message error from apple store after uploading my app to app store connect.
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "apps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file.

I have coded an ionic app, And I am trying to generate an ios version of my App with push notification.
I have created both .p12 files and I have activated push notification in apple developer and in Xcode.in capabilities. Then I have redownloaded the provisioning profile and opened it with Xcode. First I've had a red warning in 'Add the push notifications feature to your App ID'.But this problem was fixed when I restarted Xcode and Xcode detect that everything is fine.

I have generated two versions of my app the first with automatically managing signing and the other one with manual manage signing just in case that maybe Xcode wasn't able to detect my new provisioning profile but in both cases, I've got the message above.

How can I make this work? and How can I check if my app version has this app's signature entitlment.Any help please ?

Comment: In my case warning went away when I have enabled Push notifications in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
   <string>fetch</string>
   <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```